# Questions about the expected target value $\bar{y}(x)$

Tags: regression, expected-value

Assume a simple Linear Regression problem, where we have $n$ data points $x$, and one target variable $y$.

My confusion, or more precisely misconceptions start at the following equation and its definition, read in an ML book

Let $\bar{y}(x)$ the expected value of the target variable conditioned on $x$:

$\bar{y}(x) = E_{y|x}[y] = \int_y yp(y|x) dy$

Let me explain my current level of understanding when it comes to that formula:

for every point from our training data $x_n$, we know about the corresponding value $y$, assuming that $x$ and $y$ are dependent, we can assume that there is some function $f$, which computes $f(x_n) = y$. Visually, this also gives us something like this:

[image]

where the blue dots are our $y$'s, and the red line represents $f(x_n)$.
Know, for some specific $x_n$, there can be many different $y$ values, and the average of these $y$ values is our $\bar{y}(x_n)$. For continuous values in our training data, we can calculate this number by using the formula

$\bar{y}(x) = E_{y|x}[y] = \int_y yp(y|x) dy$.

Intuitively, visually I think about it like that: for a specific $x_n$, we can draw a probability distribution $p(y|x)$:

[image]

and for continuous values the mean of that distribution that be calculated with the exact formula above. Now, there can be many things already wrong here, but here are my questions:

1. How can we actually compute $p(y|x)$? I think in regression we assume that the errors are normally distributed, so we could use the gaussian pdf to compute $p(y|x)$?
2. if so, how exactly would that look like? if $y \approx N(y | \mu, \sigma)$, how do we get the mean, how the variance? Would we use the MLE to estimate these parameters?

I hope to get some clarification, the best thing would be an example, since this question has been sticking with me for quite some time now!

Comment: If you go through any textbook OLS parameter estimation proof of simple linear regression model which could lead to an equivalent MLE formulation, all the predictor values are viewed as fixed against the model (not *endogenous* rv's of the model), see today's related [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/600042/what-is-the-predictor-considered-fixed-against).

Comment: Here the regression model is only for the distribution of the r.v. y given the input x and the model parameters and the randomness is solely from the error term. This is referred to as the discriminative framework. When the inputs are also modelled as coming from a probability distribution, it is referred to as the generative framework. The former is generally more efficient and faster to train, but they can only make predictions for the ranges of training. The latter can make predictions for any range (even not present in the training), but they can be more computationally expensive to train.